# Laravel project is running but in server it is giving error

Tags: php, authentication, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

*My laravel project is running in the local but when I deploy on server project is giving error.*

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist:
> boolean = integer LINE 1: ...from "table_name" where "email" = $1 and
> "isactived" = $2 limit... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name
> and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL:
> select * from "table_name" where "email" = email@yahoo.com and
> "isactived" = 1 limit 1)

**What is the this error ? How can I solve?**

**Now this problem is solved with change the session parameter of config  file.**

Comment: Without more details (i.e. relevant code, migrations maybe) it's hard to say. Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here on SO. At first glance it would seem that isActivated is boolean and you're comparing it to int(1).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are passing to sql one value that not is the type of column, i think that you passing something like:

`"column_boolean_type = 1"`

try convert the value of var to boolean or int, depending on how your db is.